# Compatibility issues between Empathy and GTalk

Tags: linux, compatibility, google-talk, empathy

Are these IM clients compatible with Google Talk in terms of audio and video calls? I am asking this particular question due to problems arose upon initiating a video call from the Empathy client to Google Talk client. The connection is established but neither the video stream or the audio stream from the GTalk is  available on both ends of the connection. I have not yet tried calling Empathy client user from GTalk and doubt that it will work.

Answer (score 1):

> **Which video codec do I need?**
>
> - For calls between empathy and empathy, all you need is theora, which is installed by default on all distributions.
> - For calls between empathy and gtalk, you need h264 encoder. On ubuntu you can get it by installing gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly-multiverse and gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg.
>
> To know if a codec is installed, you can use that command:
>
> `$ gst-inspect-0.10 | grep 264`
>
> Make sure you have encoder and decoder in the list. For h264 you'll have x264enc encoder for example. Similar command can be used for other codecs.
>
> **Does Empathy support audio and video chat with Google Talk?**
>
> Yes, you can have a audio or video chat on the Gtalk protocol with someone using Gmail's video chat feature, Empathy or Pidgin.
>
> Note that if your contact is using Google Video, be sure he has the latest version of the plugin which can be downloaded from [this page](http://www.google.com/chat/video).

[Source](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Empathy/FAQ#Which_video_codec_do_I_need.3F)

Comment: Thanks for the answer I will have the chance to try it later on.